# If everything is made up of atoms, what is vacuum made up of?

Tags: spacetime, vacuum, matter

Do empty space in our universe exist or it is all filled with dark matter or some other unknown matter?

Comment: Not everything is made up of atoms. Pions and muons, for example, are not made of atoms, and yet they are tangible things that can interact with matter in well-defined and well-studied ways.

Answer (score 4):

“Vacuum” is often loosely defined as the *absence* of *matter*.

Interstellar and intergalactic space has a very low density of atoms, so it can be considered a vacuum to a good approximation. However, every cubic centimeter of the universe actually contains about 400 photons left over from the Big Bang, so radiation fills the universe. There are also believed to be lots of leftover neutrinos everywhere, a kind of lightweight matter. Physicists also think dark *energy* (not dark matter) is everywhere. Dark matter is believed to mainly clump around galaxies, so there is probably not much of it between galaxies.

An ideal vacuum would have no matter (including no atoms, no neutrinos, and no dark matter) and no radiation (such as photons) either. But it could still have dark energy, which is sometimes called “vacuum energy”.

Physicists think of the ideal vacuum state as the state in which there are no field *quanta* but there can nevertheless be field *energy*.

Comment: How do we explain the nothingness

Comment: @pss Why do you think nothingness needs an explanation? Most people think it is *non*-nothingness that needs to be explained.

Comment: See ....imagine when you say nothing is present in this universe ....should we think of blank space.....or what ....

Comment: @pss Have you studied quantum mechanics and the harmonic oscillator? Does the $n=0$ state need an explanation?

Comment: What nothingness is ....is it blank space or nothing....we can’t imagine I hope right?

Comment: Yes, imagine blank space.

Comment: u should by now understand...No!

Comment: But unfortunately there is another level of nothingness where there is no space or time either!

Comment: which we can’t imagine! Right?

Comment: Physicists have written papers about such nothingness, so I suppose they *can* imagine it. Or at least think about it mathematically. This is the “universe from nothing” idea.

Comment: And how do we explain the blank space ....coz I feel there exists smtng to hold the  inexistence ..and how to explain the existence of that smtng......hence we don’t have an answer or we do?  Coz I’m no where near the higher physics studies...(high school )

Comment: We explain the blank space as a “Riemannian manifold”. When you learn more mathematics or physics, you may learn about them. PSE is telling me to stop chatting, so I’m done.

Comment: sure!...thank you..